# font family query not displaying

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am trying this code to change the font. to the desired value, all the files of the font are saved in the same directory as css and html files. i am not able to find the error

```
@font-face {

    font-family:'newfont';
    src:url('../website/fonts/kulminoituva.eot');
    src:url('../website/fonts/kulminoituva.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../website/fonts/kulminoituva.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../website/fonts/kulminoituva.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

and the code while calling

```
ul li {
    font-family: 'newfont', helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

**update**

I got this runned, after just giving the file name. without any file path. the bracket automatically detects the font. 
thanks to @Calvt and appleElmi

Comment: When you inspect the page, are there any 404 errors re these fonts?

Comment: @CalvT no there are no 404 errors! the page runs successfully. the font is not displayed, that's it

Comment: @CalvT found the 404 error on two of the files. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to be a reference issue, as @CalvT was alluding to. In the description, you mention

> all the files of the font are saved in the same directory as css and html files

however, the `@font-face` declaration is indicating the fonts are in the parent directory (`..`), under /website/fonts

Check the Developer Tools of the browser and make sure there are no errors indicating:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

If the fonts *are saved in the same directory as css and html files*, under a folder called *website*, then `@font-face` declaration should be

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'newfont';
    src:url('website/fonts/kulminoituva.eot');
    src:url('website/fonts/kulminoituva.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('website/fonts/kulminoituva.woff') format('woff'),
        url('website/fonts/kulminoituva.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

If they are *saved in the same directory as css and html files* under a folder called *fonts*, then remove *website/* from your `@font-face` declaration

Comment: yes found the error as @CalvT alluded. 
its a 404 error! my bad